# Storing shapes drawn on canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I am trying to make a component for an application which a user can use to create simple UML diagrams . The idea is that the user will drag & drop the shapes on canvas and then add some text to it .

The problem is that I haven't done anything similar before or anything that has to do with graphics(except GUI).

What I would like to ask is how I would be able to store the state of a canvas so it can be serialised and send to another canvas to be redrawn.

Would I be able to save coordinates on a text document and send that document ? If not how such operations are done usually ? Thanks

Comment: See also [ArgoUML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArgoUML).

Comment: You mean the source code ? I am making something way more basic.

Comment: @latusaki something more basic http://stackoverflow.com/a/8588028/714968

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easiest way would be store `Graphics` Objects in the `Set`, `Map`, `Vector`, `Array` or in the separate `Class` that hold your `Objects` ([nice answer to my question by @trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616169/714968)) before painting in `paintComponent` method, then there you can prepare `Object` for painting (meaning remove, add, modify, clone or compare)

Comment: See also [`GraphPanel`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel).

Comment: Thanks that gives me something to start with !